# How to get download url of a digital file stored in an Azure storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

After storing a `digital file` in `Azure blob storage`, I want to provide a `link` to that file in my `static website` (that has `no` server side code). When a user clicks on that link user should be able to download that digital file to his/her computer. **Question**: How do you get the `url` of a digital file stored in Azure blob storage?

Comment: You mean something like https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container-name/digital-file-name?

Comment: @GauravMantri A URL of my digital file in Azure blob storage that - when a user clicks on - should immediately download the digital file to his/her computer (download folder). User's browser would of course give a warning if you want to download this file - but that is off topic here.

Comment: Provided an answer. Not sure if this is what you're looking for. HTH.

Answer (score 9):

Each blob in Azure Storage has a URL of the following format:

```
https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/blob
```

Where:

`account` is the name of your storage account, `container` is the name of your blob container`and`blob` is the name of your blob.

Now that your requirement is that a user should be prompted to download the file directly without using any server-side code, these are the additional things you would need to do:

1. Make sure that the blob container's ACL is either set to `Blob` (recommended) or `Public`. If you set the ACL to `Private`, then you would need a `Shared Access Signature (SAS)` and that would require some server-side code.
2. Either set the `content-type` of the blob to `application/octet-stream` (default content type for any blob in Azure Storage) or set the `content-disposition` property to `attachment; filename="your file name"` to force the file download instead of displaying it inside the browser only. Recommended approach is to use `content-disposition` property.