# Azure blob storage Error: The specified resource does not exist

Tags: python, api, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload file in Azure blob storage through REST API. Acess level for container is set to - Container(anonymous read access to container and bolb).

Sharing code and response for the reference-

```
filepath = "/home/meera/Downloads/download.pdf"
account_name = "account_name"
container_name = "container_name"
name = "doc.pdf"
sas_token = "sas_token"

with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
    file_content = f.read() 
headers = { "Content-Type": "application/pdf; charset=UTF-8", "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob" }
url = "https://"+ account_name+".blob.core.windows.net/"+container_name+"/"+name+sas_token
response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=file_content)
```

Error: `<Response [404]> <Code>ResourceNotFound</Code><Message>The specified resource does not exist.`

Comment: Have you checked if the container exists in the storage account?

Comment: It is there. I created the container as follows:-

1) On the Azure Portal, go to Storage Account => Blob service => Containers

2) Click '+ Container', give it a name, and set 'Public access level' to 'Container (anonymous read access for containers and blobs)'

Comment: This is totally weird. Normally you should get 404 error while uploading a blob when the container is not present.

Comment: @GauravMantri I'm able to upload file in container now. Getting 201, however in the response I don't find any url to download the file. When we upload file in GCP in the response we get one URL to dowmload the file. In Azure how can we get url to download the file??  I was searching in google and found this link. I want to do same as posted in this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60583797/how-to-get-download-url-of-a-digital-file-stored-in-an-azure-storage-account

Comment: Basically you're executing REST API directly (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob) and that's why you're not getting the URL back. You can use my answer (which you linked in your comment) to get the blob URL or you should use Azure Storage Python SDK instead of directly calling REST API. There you will get the Blob URL.

Comment: With rest api also we can get url and it's done. :)

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I am able to get blob downloadable URL

Answer (score 0):

Of course your solution is great, but we always use python-sdk in code like this:

```
            # [START upload_a_blob]
            # Upload content to block blob
            with open(SOURCE_FILE, "rb") as data:
                blob_client.upload_blob(data, blob_type="BlockBlob")
            # [END upload_a_blob]

            # [START download_a_blob]
            with open(DEST_FILE, "wb") as my_blob:
                download_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
                my_blob.write(download_stream.readall())
            # [END download_a_blob]
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-samples-python?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json

Using rest api requires some headers, check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob